# How to set initial value to a FormArray control in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to add an initial value to a FormArray control. I am using this code:

```
    if(this.navParams.get('kids').length > 1) {
        for(let i=0; i<this.navParams.get('kids').length - 1; i++) {
            this.addChild();
        }
        for(let i=0; i<this.navParams.get('kids').length; i++) {
            this.registrationForm.controls['child'][i]['child_first_name'].setValue("asdasdasd");
        }
    }
```

However, I think I am using setValue method in a wrong way. 
I am having this error:

[image: Error]

Here is the code for addChild:

```
addChild() {
    // add child to the list
    const control = <FormArray>this.registrationForm.controls['child'];
    control.push(this.initChild());
    // console.log(this.registrationForm.value);
}
```

Here is the initChild Method:

```
initChild() {
    // initialize child form
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        child_first_name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(255), Validators.required])],
        child_last_name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(255), Validators.required])],
        child_gender: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        child_bdate: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
}
```

I am finding a solution for like almost 2 days. This is my first time to use Ionic. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, SO community!

Comment: Can you add code of addChild method?

Comment: Edited the question and I added the addCHild and initChild method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way of doing that is using `get` method like:

```
this.registrationForm.get(['child', i, 'child_first_name']).setValue('asdasdasd');
```

If you use controls property then it should look as follows:

```
((this.registrationForm.controls['child'] as FormArray).controls[i] as FormGroup).controls['child_first_name'].setValue("asdasdasd");
```

one more alternative could look like:

```
this.registrationForm.patchValue({
  child: [...Array(i), { child_first_name: 'asdasdasd' }]
});
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8cldka?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)**

Comment: Woah! Thank you so much @yurzui :) You save my whole week! haha! :D